# Validate if data that are sent to database actually come from frontend

Tags: hibernate, validation, frontend, backend

I've got a theoretical question. Say we have an application with a formular in the frontend to fill (JavaScript/Angular). We type in a value and send it to the backend (Java/Hibernate) to write this value into a database.

Now the question: In the backend, is there a possibility to validate if the data that we want to write into the database, actually come from the frontend? I would like to validate exactly this case and I am fairly new to this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To put it differently, are you trying to verify that any particular database record was not inserted by an individual who has access to it, but they were rather results of user actions through UI?

Comment: yes, exactly :)